# How do you figure out an efficient battery setup?

Tags: arduino, batteries

I have a project where I need an arduino uno and 4 dc motors to run on batteries. My first thought was that I'll just hook up 3 or 4 AAs to the arduino and a 9V to the motor drivers.

I googled to be safe and the internet consensus seemed like that method would be very inefficient. Voltage wasn't the problem but apparently 9V have very low current and I'd be wasting money, and the arduino wastes current like a madman. Most solutions involved buying additional hardware. **Is there a way I can efficiently power my project without buying more chips?**

Even just guidance on how to calculate a better setup would be very appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross-posted on Arduino.SE

Answer (score 3):

> and the arduino wastes current like a madman

what do you mean by this? I suspect it consumes about 25 mA. And also I suspect your motors take far more.

So with 2500 mA*h accumulators your arduino should work for about 100 hours. However I could not say anything definite about your motors since you keep their parameters in secret :)

> apparently 9V have very low current

what it is about? do you mean some particular 9V battery? the principle is rather simple here - the larger battery have the larger store of energy.

> without buying more chips?

No chips will create you additional energy from nothing. So basically you check the current of motors, multiply by hours you want them to work - and you got the capacity parameter for batteries...